# Can I send a v1.0 Facebook app through the review process?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an old Facebook app that is currently using the v1.0 API.
I am planning to migrate to v2.2 before April 30th, 2015. 
I would like to request a new extended permission for my app, but I am afraid that during the review process Facebook will automatically bump my app to v2.0 in the process. Is this true?

Is it safe to submit a new review request for apps still using v1.0, before April 30th? Thanks

Comment: no it is not true. There is no danger in submitting it

Comment: The reason I asked is because I already tested this and it seemed to be the case. I had an old app that would return all the user's friends for /me/friends, but after the facebook review process the exact same code now only returns friends that use the app. Do you know anything else that could have caused this?